# Footnote inside tabular inside longtable

Tags: tables, footnotes, longtable

I have a foontone inside a tabular environment inside longtable and of course it does not work. Has anyone faced something similar? What should i do ?

Thanks in advance

Vasilis

```
 \begin{center}
 \begin{longtable}{|m{0.15\textwidth}|m{0.45\textwidth}|m{0.40\textwidth}|}
 \hline
 Μεταβλητή & Περιγραφή & Παράδειγμα \\ \hline
 \endfirsthead 

 \hline Μεταβλητή & Περιγραφή & Παράδειγμα \endhead \hline

 \hline \multicolumn{3}{|r|}{{Συνέχεια στην επόμενη σελίδα}} \\ \hline
 \endfoot

 \hline \hline
 \endlastfoot

 Συναρτήσεις &


 {\begin{tabular}{@{}m{0.45\textwidth}@{}}
 Οι συναρτήσεις θα πρέπει να είναι \en{camelCased}\footnote{CamelCase είναι η πρακτική της γραφής σύνθετων λέξεων ή φράσεων, έτσι ώστε κάθε λέξη ή σύντμηση να αρχίζει με ένα κεφαλαίο γράμμα \cite{wiki:camelCase}.} και οι μεταβλητές να είναι όλες πεζές, με κάτω παύλες (\_) μεταξύ των λέξεων.
 \\ \hline

 Ο τύπος επιστροφής της κάθε συνάρτησης θα πρέπει να τοποθετείται σε διαφορετική γραμμή \\ \hline

 Πρέπει να διαλέγετε ως όνομα ένα ρήμα το οποίο αντανακλά την δράση της συνάρτησης. Καλό είναι να επιλέγονται ονόματα τα οποία αντανακλούν στοιχεία του προβλήματος από όχι την επίλυση του προβλήματος.

 \end{tabular}} &

 {\begin{lstlisting}
 int
 applyExample (int example_arg);

 void
 checkForErrors();
 \end{lstlisting}}
 \\ \hline

 \caption{Ονοματολογια}
 \label{table:naming_conventions}
 \end{longtable}
 \end{center}
```

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use \footnotemark within the tabular and then set \footnotetext{} to the content of the footnote outside that environment:

```
 \begin{center}
 \begin{longtable}{|m{0.15\textwidth}|m{0.45\textwidth}|m{0.40\textwidth}|}
 \hline
 Μεταβλητή & Περιγραφή & Παράδειγμα \\ \hline
 \endfirsthead

 \hline Μεταβλητή & Περιγραφή & Παράδειγμα \endhead \hline

 \hline \multicolumn{3}{|r|}{{Συνέχεια στην επόμενη σελίδα}} \\ \hline
 \endfoot

 \hline \hline
 \endlastfoot

 Συναρτήσεις &


 {\begin{tabular}{@{}m{0.45\textwidth}@{}}
 Οι συναρτήσεις θα πρέπει να είναι \en{camelCased}\footnotemark και οι μεταβλητές να είναι όλες πεζές, με κάτω παύλες (\_) μεταξύ των λέξεων.
 \\ \hline

 Ο τύπος επιστροφής της κάθε συνάρτησης θα πρέπει να τοποθετείται σε διαφορετική γραμμή \\ \hline

 Πρέπει να διαλέγετε ως όνομα ένα ρήμα το οποίο αντανακλά την δράση της συνάρτησης. Καλό είναι να επιλέγονται ονόματα τα οποία αντανακλούν στοιχεία του προβλήματος από όχι την επίλυση του προβλήματος.

 \end{tabular}} &

 {\begin{lstlisting}
 int
 applyExample (int example_arg);

 void
 checkForErrors();
 \end{lstlisting}}
 \\ \hline

 \caption{Ονοματολογια}
 \label{table:naming_conventions}
 \end{longtable}
 \footnotetext{CamelCase είναι η πρακτική της γραφής σύνθετων λέξεων ή φράσεων, έτσι ώστε κάθε λέξη ή σύντμηση να αρχίζει με ένα κεφαλαίο γράμμα \cite{wiki:camelCase}.}
 \end{center}
```

I won't post my output because it looks horribly messy as I couldn't figure out everything needed to get your code to compile. (So the footnote marker and footnote show OK but not a lot else.)

Comment: Thanks it works !!! The only thing i changed was the place of the footnotetext so the footnote would appear in the same page. When i finish my assignment i will try to post the code for the latex in github so anyone can use it.